# Volley Library Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I have a question about google volley library. I created a php file to check the following states

1. is it a post request
2. what variable it will become

This look like these

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showClassmates();
}

function showClassmates(){
    global $connect;

    if(isset($_POST['table'])){

        $row = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, strtolower($_POST['table']));

        $query = " Select * FROM $row; ";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $temp_array = array();

        if($number_of_rows > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $temp_array[] = $row;
            }
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        echo json_encode(array("classmates"=>$temp_array));
        mysqli_close($connect);

    }

}
```

Now I want to load this list with an android application. I created a layout resources for this. After that I have read the volley documentation and I think it's a good idea to load the json data from mysql table. But I don't know how to make in one request the table name and load the header charset list. Has anyone an idea? Thanks for help :D

Oh and this is an homework project from my teacher, i think he hates me xD But the important thing is, it will be rated :(

Comment: _Oh and this is an homework project..._ Do your homework yourself please....

Comment: Yeah, i do it by myself. But it doesn't work what i've tryed

Comment: you want to fetch data from php to android using volley right..

Comment: yeap this is what i tryed

Comment: ok wait i will answer

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to fetch the json data, but how i can fix the problem with the post[table]?

> JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
>   
> (Request.Method.POST,
>   
>                 showUrl, new Response.Listener() {
>   
>             @Override
>   
>             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
>   
>                 try {
>   
>                     JSONArray products = response.getJSONArray("products");
>   
>   
>                    for (int i = 0; i < classmates.length(); i++) {
>   
>                         JSONObject classmatelist = classmates.getJSONObject(i);
>   
>   
>                       String classmate = product.getString("classmate");
>   
>   
>                        items.add(classmates);
>   
>                     }
>   
>                 } catch (JSONException e) {
>   
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>   
>                 }
>   
>                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>   
>             }
>   
>         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>   
>             @Override
>   
>             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>   
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_toast, >Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>   
>             }
>   
>        });
>   
>        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);